Forgotten Realms maps, why the changes of scale?
Recently, I went looking at various maps of The Forgotten Realms, from generally looking at Faerun, to looking specifically at The Sword Coast.
From what I can find, in 2nd edition, this map features a scale that puts Neverwinter about 350 miles from Waterdeep.
Meanwhile, this map from 3rd edition has a scale that puts them about 240 miles apart.
This map from 4th edition also features the scale for 240 miles.
But this map from the Storm King's Thunder features a scale that makes that distance about 330 miles.
Is there an explanation anywhere about why the scale has shifted between the editions? And which scale is more consistent with Greenwood's writings?

Just a reminder, to prevent a flood of speculative answers:  Answers need to be backed up with relevant evidence.

Reminder to everyone that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, etc. do not belong in comments.

Edit as of Aug 30, '24: I am leaving this "answer" available for the links, and removing any speculation.
I discovered this discussion on Enworld:
Forgotten Realms Geographic Changes, which links to this Reddit post:
The Changing Size of Faerun.
From the Reddit post, it appears that Faerun in 5th edition is the same size and approximate shape as in 2nd edition.
From the Enworld discussion, it appears that for 3rd edition, Faerun/Toril was significantly and radically reduced in size, partly by cutting out parts of the map.
As a result of the linked discussion and post, I did look at some differences between the maps for 2nd, 3rd, and 5th edition, and it does appear that the 5th edition map is an approximate return to the map of 2nd edition.

This seems to be entirely speculative, so I’ve downvoted.

@ThomasMarkov I know of no official statement on this, so yes, speculative. How would you suggest I word this to account for that better?

I wouldn’t word it at all. This is just a guess based on other people also just guessing. This isn’t the sort of answer we’re looking for on stack exchange. It’s an interesting discussion, appropriate for a traditional discussion forum, but this isn’t a traditional discussion forum.
